# PyInstaller and pykeyboard aren't working together

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have PyInstaller and pykeyboard on my computer. I am trying to create a helpful python program and compile it in to a Linux executable with PyInstaller.
Every time I do this, so long as pykeyboard is imported in the script, it creates the executable, but the executable does not run. It comes back with an error.

I've tried compiling my script without pykeyboard and it works, but I would really like to use pykeyboard and get past this error.

Error shown below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/root/Desktop/Python/Modules/PyInstaller/PyInstaller-2.1/PyInstaller/loader/pyi_importers.py", line 270, in load_module
  File "/home/abigor/Desktop/Scripting/Python/Modules/PyInstaller/PyInstaller-2.1/test/build/test/out00-PYZ.pyz/pykeyboard", line 37, in <module>
  File "/root/Desktop/Python/Modules/PyInstaller/PyInstaller-2.1/PyInstaller/loader/pyi_importers.py", line 270, in load_module
  File "/home/abigor/Desktop/Scripting/Python/Modules/PyInstaller/PyInstaller-2.1/test/build/test/out00-PYZ.pyz/pykeyboard.x11", line 21, in <module>
  File "/root/Desktop/Python/Modules/PyInstaller/PyInstaller-2.1/PyInstaller/loader/pyi_importers.py", line 270, in load_module
  File "/home/abigor/Desktop/Scripting/Python/Modules/PyInstaller/PyInstaller-2.1/test/build/test/out00-PYZ.pyz/Xlib.XK", line 63, in <module>
  File "/home/abigor/Desktop/Scripting/Python/Modules/PyInstaller/PyInstaller-2.1/test/build/test/out00-PYZ.pyz/Xlib.XK", line 44, in load_keysym_group
ImportError: No module named keysymdef.miscellany
```

I should also note that the pykeyboard module for Python is actually named "PyUserInput", but to import it from Python you must import "pykeyboard". I forgot to mention that earlier.